# Установка значений в файле styles.xml по умолчанию

Tags: android, xml

Имеется вопрос: при создании проекта, каждый раз при добавлении чего-либо на макет, ничего не отображается. Прогуглил, оказалось, чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо изменить в styles.xml на `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
Однако это приходится делать каждый раз при создании проекта. Можно ли где-то это поменять, чтобы тема была измененная по умолчанию?

Comment: Тоже как-то интересовался этим вопросом, но так и не выяснил до конца. Я так понимаю что темы зависят не от студии напряму, а от той версиеи sdk которую Вы используете.

Comment: `<папка установки Android Studio>/plugins/android/lib/templates` - там лежат шаблоны по которым всё создаётся. Править сам не пробовал - не подскажу. Только скорее всего при следующем обновлении студии они будут перезаписаны.

Comment: это баг новой версии студии и его скоро должны исправить, не стоит зацикливаться на этом и что то менять

Answer (score 0):

Тему на все приложение можно установить через AndroidManifest, через тег theme

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```